# Dynamic Programming and alike in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, rules

I need to learn a certain programming subject and I don't know where to start, would like your help.

This is what I need do do, I have a user form (UI) and the user enter "Rules" in the form of:
if operator(obj1) then assign(obj1,string)...

I take this rules, and translate them into actual code, and I want to put that code somewhere in a function/my code.

for example:

```
main {

UI...
/* when we reach here, means the user done writing rules */

/*Function that translate the user rules to actual code */
translate();

for {
/* This is where I want to put the code after translation */
}
}
```

How do I put the code inside the loop (or anywhere else for that matters) after the program started running?

I ofcourse don't look for an actual answer, more to give you an idea what I need so you can refer me to a certain subject to study about.

Comment: I think you should read some tutorials on this subject first.

Comment: This question is *far* too vague. You will need to think a lot more about this subject, and SO is not the place to do long conceptual discussions.

Comment: I understand that, But can you give me the name of the subject to study about? Is it just dynamic programming?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "programming" is the name of the subject you're describing.

Comment: Allright let me simplfy stuff, lets say I have a string that contains "if (i==1) then (i=2);" , how can I put that string into an actual code in a ceratin function?

Comment: Seems like really all you're asking is how to make your program perform different tasks depending on a value specified by the user? Because you'd learn that within the first hour of any programming course.

Comment: Oh okay I get it now. Try researching "runtime evaluation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume, you are in process of creating a custom rule engine, which has the capability of validating your rules on fly. Within my ability, you need to start reading c# scripting, code generation, dynamic loading or reflection etc are some to start with.

To give a kick start, following are some of the step which I can think off;

1. Grab the rule definition (xml or csv)
2. Write a small helper which will read rule entries from the definition and convert it into
   c# source code. This is similar to c# scripting.
3. On successful completion of (2), create a dll out of the source code
4. Now reflect/dynamically load the dll from (3) to where ever you wanted to validate the rule.

Comment: @user2915058, With pleassure